# Scaled dragable image goes out of bounds of DIV element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zooming

I have draggable image object in div element (image can't be dragged outside div). Also I made a zoom slider for that draggable image, but problem is then I'm zooming the image it goes outside the div bounds (when image is draged and zoomed near div bound). To fix it i have to drag it anywhere to get stucked again in its div. Is there a way when zooming to keep image inside div element which is overlapped by zoomed image (max image zoom is not bigger than div element). Hope you understood my question. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
      $( ".over_image" ).draggable({ cursor: "move", cursorAt: { top: 30, left: 80 } });
      $( ".over_image" ).draggable({ containment: "parent", scroll: false });
}); 
   $("#slider").slider({
                    step: 2,
                    min: 75,
                    max: 220,
                    value: 150,
                    slide: function(e,ui){
                        var sliderValue =  jQuery("#slider").slider("value");
                        $(".over_image").width(sliderValue);

                    }
                });



<div class="wraper">
     <div id="output" class="foto-frame">
 <img class="over_image" id="img_1" src="1.png" width="100" height="auto" />
     </div>
<div id="progressbox"><div id="progressbar"></div ></div>
<div class="nav-buttons">
     <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Image cant go out of `#output` div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this attribute to the div class:

```
.foto-frame {
        overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: That didint help. Picture still overlapping DIV element. I think because picture has absolute position, because I need to add this picture on top of other picture, that filled the div element